# How to show first four characters in password and display the asterisk next to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display the first four characters and show the asterisk using namespacing from a password input field:

```
users.page.passChar = userInput => {
    let emptyStr = "";
    if (userInput) {
        emptyStr = userInput.substring(3);
        emptyStr.replace();
    }
    return emptyStr;
}
```

Comment: Could you add some test input and expected output?  I.e userInput="abc123" should result in "abc1**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question properly you want to replace asterisks to the end of the string and only display the first four characters?

This should be a good start:

```js
function passDisplay(userInput) {
    let emptyStr = "";
    if (userInput) {
        emptyStr = userInput.substring(0, 4);
        if (userInput.length > 3) {
           emptyStr += Array(userInput.length - 4).fill('*').join('');
        }
    }
    return emptyStr;
}
console.log(passDisplay("hunter2"));
```

Comment: Yes that did the trick! Can you explain how its working? Thanks!

Comment: The `fill('*')` method fills all the elements of an array from a start index to an end index with a static value. The `join('')` method joins all those asterisks rather than separate them with commas. If you provided `join(',')` or a different character the asterisks would be separated by whatever character is provided to the method.

Answer (score 1):

One option using `reduce`:

```js
const passChar = userInput => (
    [...userInput].reduce((input, char, i) => `${input}${(i > 3) ? '*' : char }`, '')
);

console.log(passChar('password'));
```

Comment: Or `userInput.split('').reduce(` if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

So, I assume you're looking for 'abc123' to display 'abc1**', based on your described functionality.

Given that, you'll want your function to look like this:

```
function passDisplay(userInput) {
  let result = '';
  if(userInput) {
    result = userInput.substring(0,4);
    if(userInput.length > 3) {
      result += Array(userInput.length - 4).fill('*').join('');
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```